# set histchars not working in zsh

Tags: zsh, command-history, history-expansion

Consider the following commands for overriding the history expansion characters (which I got from *Learning Shell Scripting with ZSH* book):

```
% set histchars='@^#'
% ls *.txt
file1.txt  file2.txt
% @@
```

Result:

```
zsh: command not found: @@
```

However, this works (note that `set` is omitted):

```
% histchars='@^#' 
% ls *.txt       
file1.txt  file2.txt
% @@
```

Result:

```
ls *.txt
file1.txt  file2.txt
```

I tried both with my `.zshrc` and with a vanilla shell (`zsh --no-rcs`), the result is the same.

Question: is the `set ...` syntax wrong in the book, or am I missing something?

Comment: Is it actually giving you the command `set histchars='@^#'`, or is it telling you to "_set_ `histchars='@^#'`" (which may have been better phrased as "set the `histchars` variable to the string `@^#`")?

Comment: `set histchars='@^#'` is csh variable assignment syntax (and csh is the shell that introduced history expansion in the late 70s). scalar variable assignment syntax in zsh is shaped after the Bourne shell's one (also from the late 70s, zsh took the best from bourne/c/korn shells and added much more of its own). So `histchars='@^#'`

Comment: @Kusalananda: yes, it is written exactly like this: `% set histchars='@^#'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: so if I understand correctly, that syntax is wrong in ZSH, right?

Comment: I thought that maybe some parameter is not set correctly in the zshrc script, but apparently that's not the case then.

Comment: https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch30_15.htm shows something  similar for csh, explaining zsh extended histchars, not clarifying that zsh's variable assignment syntax is different from that of csh

Comment: Note like the default prompt character in zsh is `%`, the same as in csh and the same as in the original Unix shell by Ken Thompson. The Bourne shell changed it to `$` for some reason.